# Обработка json данных в Zabbix 3.4

Tags: python, json, zabbix

Необходимо обрабатывать метрики, передаваемые из хоста по http протоколу в формате JSON. Например есть URL http://10.0.#.#:8081/metrics/:

```
{"memory": 198286984,
 "max_queue_length": 0,
 "connections": 1000,
 "bad_packets_counter": 26127,
 "bad_packets_counter_per_minute": 0,
 "bytes_received": 187695,
 "bytes_sent": 114262,
 "buffer_counter": 11,
 "kafka_failures_per_minute": 0,
 "kafka_failures_per_day": 0,
 "kafka_records_with_server_utc": 0}
```

Каким образом можно загрузить эти данные в zabbix, чтобы можно было построить графики по выбранному параметру и создать триггеры?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если на узле стоит zabbix-agent, то через UserParameter в **zabbix-
agentd.conf**

На агенте что-то вроде:

```
UserParameter=metric.[*],/path/to/script $1
```

script - дербанит JSON и забирает оттуда нужный параметр

На сервере создаете значение, для соответствуещего узла сети: Тип - zabbix agent (active); Key - metric.memory и так для каждого параметра.

Второй вариант, если нет возможности ставить агента на целевом узле, сдел замутить скрипт который дербанит JSON и пихучить параметры в zabbix, по одному, с помощью zabbix_sender. 
Для узла должны быть созданы соответствующие значения.

Извиняюсь, не обратил внимания на версию. Для 3.4 смотрите [тут](http://unixtoys.blogspot.ru/2017/10/zabbix-34-and-dependent-items.html) и [тут](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/ru/manual/config/items/itemtypes/dependent_items)

По сути нужно настроить только свой шаблон в препроцессинге, который будет выдергивать данные из JSON. На discovery можно не обращать внимания

Если будут трудности уже в процессе настройки,пишите! Удачи!

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ. Поробую.

Answer (score 2):

Создаем item, который будет забирать json с сервера:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Переходим в закладку Preprocessing и добавляем регулярку, которая будет вырезать JSON:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Готово, теперь можно создавать дочерние элементы. Например memory:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И настраиваем Preprocessing:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Аналогично добавляем остальные элементы.

Comment: Закомментировал UserParameter. Скрипт не использую.

Answer (score 0):

Итак, первый вопрос. Я написал несколько скриптов, какой из них более подходит для решения данной задачи?

первый: курлом возвращает результат запроса (результат возврата в шапке)

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -s http://10.0.#.#:8081/metrics/
```

второй: возращает значение connections

```
#!/bin/bash
export PYTHONENCODING=utf8

curl -s 'http://10.0.#.#:8081/metrics/' | \
    python3 -c "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['connections'])"
```

Поскольку я использовал первый вариант, то UserParameter у меня следующего вида. 
UserParameter=metric.[*],/etc/zabbix/get_json.sh $1 $2

Далее в Zabbix. Создал элемент данных следующего вида:

```
Имя: getMetrics
Тип: Zabbix агент
Ключ: metric
Тип информации: текст
Группы элемнтов данных: Internal Items
```

Предобработка: Путь JSON > .connections (1 параметр) и Путь JSON > .memory (2 параметр)

В информации о состоянии пишет что неподдерживаемый элемент ключа.

Comment: Для 3.4 можно забить на UserParameter, это для младших версий. Можно сделать проще

Answer (score 0):

Создал элемент данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прописал шаги предобработки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возникает ошибка:

```
Item preprocessing step #1 failed: cannot perform regular expression 
match on value "" of type "string": pattern does not match.
```

Comment: 1. Формат для web.page.get другой, должно быть: web.page.get[10.0.5.55,/metric,8081]
2. В "Предобработке" должен быть только 1  пункт, где выдергивается только JSON.
Таким образом получиться родительский элемент, на базе которого нужно будет делать дочерние.
Для memory и connections нужно создавать отдельные элементы. Т.е. в итоге должно получиться три "элемента данных"

Comment: Item создается. Никак не могу разобраться с предобработкой. Выставил регулярное выражение, прописал параметры > вывод.

Zabbix ругается
9369:20171115:145826.879 error reason for "Zabbix server:web.page.get[10.0.5.55,/metrics,8081]" changed: Item preprocessing step #1 failed: cannot perform regular expression match on value "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
connection: close
content-length: 0
date: Wed, 15 Nov 2017 11:58:26 GMT
server: Cowboy" of type "string": pattern does not match

Comment: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found - так говорит страница не найден. Я не знаю как у вас организовано веб-приложение, может попробовать так - server:web.page.get[10.0.5.55,/metrics/,8081].

Добавить / - после metrics

Answer (score 0):

Увы, я так и не понял как реализовать решение этой задачи без агента. Пробую через агента.

В итоге я немного изменил скрипт, положил в директорию /etc/zabbix/externalscripts. Дал соответсвующие права и т.д.

```
#!/bin/bash
export PYTHONENCODING=utf8

curl -s 'http://10.0.5.55:8081/metrics/' | \
    python3 -c "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['$1'])"
```

Если я выполню скрипт через терминал, я могу вытащить любое значение, указав интересующий ключ:

```
unixander@zabbix-server:/etc/zabbix/externalscripts$ ./kafka_prod.sh connections
952
unixander@zabbix-server:/etc/zabbix/externalscripts$ ./kafka_prod.sh memory
220638384
```

Внес изменения в конфиг сервера и агента.

zabbix_server.conf:

```
ExternalScripts=/etc/zabbix/externalscripts
```

zabbix_agentd.conf:

```
UnsafeUserParameters=1
UserParameter=kafka_prod[*],/etc/zabbix/externalscripts/kafka_prod.sh $1
```

Иду в заббикс, создаю элемент данных и тут у меня снова ступор, как и с предобработкой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для проверки, что все ОК, я хочу вытащить пока что connections и memory. Как правильно прописать поле key и шаги предобработки?

Comment: В таком случае, предобработка уже не нужна. Достаточно в поле key элемента connections указать kafka_prod[connections], а для memory, соответственно kafka_prod[memory]

Comment: Всё работает как часы, спасибо за помощь!